# Android making base activity class

Tags: android, inheritance

**Doubt:**

I am having a main activity which i am extending from another activity class.

Main Activity extends NewClass   (Newclass extends Activity)

I am having OnCreateDialog(int id) defined in both the classes but i am handling the case for it in the super class by super.OnCreateDialog(), even though this is getting called in the super, the dialog just doesnt appear. The dialog will appear only if it is handled in the subclass.. Why is this behaviour ?

Comment: Hard to say from here. Can you show the code?

Comment: got the issue. i was returning null in the subclass...

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue, i was returning null in the subclass instead of returning super.onCreateDialog(id);